# jest mock function that returns an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have a function that returns a object

```
function getSettings() {
  return {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
}
```

And I have a function that uses the function above internally

```
function myFunction() {
  const { foo } = getSettings()

  return foo
}
```

And I have a test that I want to change the value of `foo`

```
it('', async () => {
  const value = '123'

  const fooObj = {value: '123'}
  jest.spyOn(getSettings, 'foo').mockReturnValue(fooObj )

  const result = myFunction()

  expect(result).toBe(value)
})
```

[image]

But this doesn't work. Any ideia how to mock the return value of `getSettings`?

Comment: What is `def` do you mean `function`?

Comment: sorry, too much python... edited

Comment: Try doing const `fooObj = {value: '123'}`, and pass that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### After question edit (attaching the error image) and code update

You cant do `jest.spyOn(getSettings, 'foo')` you need to put the object/module in the first argument and the second argument should be the function name.

You can test it by changing it to:

```js
const fileWithGetSetting = require('<your-path>');

it('', async () => {
  // the key should be foo and not value
  const fooObj = {foo: '123'}

  jest.spyOn(fileWithGetSetting, 'getSettings').mockReturnValue(fooObj)

  const result = myFunction()

  expect(result).toBe(fooObj.foo)
})
```

---

If `foo` is primitive (like in your test), you need to update the object property if the value

```js
function myFunction() {
  const settings = getSettings()
  // operation on setting.foo (if foo is primitive)
  return setting.foo
}
```

And pass the object in the test and not the primitive value

```js
it('', async () => {
  const obj = {foo: '123'}

  jest.spyOn(getSettings, 'foo').mockReturnValue(obj)

  const result = myFunction()

  expect(result).toBe(obj.foo)
})
```

When you passed `foo` in your tests you passed it by value, you need to pass it by reference

Comment: This was an example. The error is on the line `jest.spyOn`

Comment: Any ideia on how to test this?

Comment: I got the error: 

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined`

Comment: jest.spyOn(fileWithGetSetting, 'getSettings').mockReturnValue(obj)

Comment: You still need the `.mockReturnValue`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237104/discussion-between-raz-luvaton-and-rodrigo).

Comment: It doesn't work by your latest code as the key is `value` and not `foo`